# Behavour of logarithmic function; from Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

The following is quoted from Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:

> As to the behavior of $\log x$ as $x\to+\infty$ and as $x\to 0$, Theorem $8.6(e)$ shows that
>   \begin{align}
> &\log x\to+\infty &&\text{as }x\to+\infty\\
> &\log x\to-\infty &&\text{as }x\to0
> \end{align}
>
> **8.6  Theorem:** Let $e^x$ be defined on $\mathbb R^1$ by $(35)$ and $(25)$. Then
>
> $(e)\:\:\:\:$ $e^x\to+\infty\ \text{ as }\ x\to+\infty,\:\ e^x\to 0\ \text{ as }\ x\to-\infty$;

Can anyone show how Rudin uses Theorem 8.6?

I would be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $\log$ is defined as the inverse of $\exp$? Then their graphs are mirror images with respect to the first bisector $x=y.$ Also, both functions are strictly increasing (because one of them is).

For example, let us show that $\log x$ becomes arbitrarily large for sufficiently small $x.$

Pick $M>0,$ we will find $r\in\mathbb R$ such that for all $x>r,$ $\log x>M.$

In fact it is sufficient to choose $r=e^M$ because then $\log x>\log r=M.$

Comment: Yes it's defined as inverse function. But how to get these limits using Theorem 8.6?

Comment: Can you explain it more extended?

Answer (score -1):

I think he is implying this:

Since $\log$ is inverse function of $\exp$,

$$
e^x \to 0 \implies x\to -\infty \implies \log x \to -\infty\;\; \text{as}\;\; x\to 0
$$

or

$$
\lim_{e^x\to 0} x = \lim_{x\to 0} \log x = -\infty
$$

Think of $e^x$ as an independent variable, then $x$ (now as a "function" of $e^x$) should go to $-\infty$ as $e^x\to 0$. So you kind of "change the roles" of dependant/independant variables.

Similarly,

$$
e^x\to \infty \implies x\to +\infty \implies \log x\to +\infty \;\; \text{as}\;\; x\to +\infty
$$